# PHP & MySQL Tagging system logic

Tags: php, html, mysql, data-structures, tags

I am a beginner developer and i would like to ask some advice.

I am currently building a platform where people will be allowed to upload images and tag them.

I was reading through some articles with the following structure to store tags

**Storing Logic 1**

```
| photo_id |     name     |            tags            |
|     1    |  some photo  | flower, sun. island, beach |
|     2    |  some photo2 | hawaii, travle. surf       |
```

Lot of people said this is not such a good idea

So my logic.

I was reading around about Many-to-Many relations and i came up with this logic

**Tags table**

```
| tag_id   |   name   |
-----------------------
|     1    |  flower  |
|     2    |  hawaii  |
|     3    |  surfing |
|     4    |  island  |
|     5    |  travel  |
```

**Photos table**

```
| photo_id |     name     |
---------------------------
|     1    |  some photo  |
|     2    |  some photo2 |
```

**Relation table**

```
| tag_id   |   photo_id   |
---------------------------
|     1    |       1      |
|     2    |       1      |
|     3    |       1      |
|     4    |       2      |
|     5    |       2      |
```

I have chosen to use [Laravel framework](http://laravel.com/) to make the development easier

But my problem is with **logic 2** and what i am scared of is it will generate a huge load time.

Because there will be no default just user based tags i thought about the following logic.

User uploads the image with tags, before image is saved, check if the actual tags exsit if not save it, than return `tags_id` and save it to the relation table with `photo_id`

So i have 2 questions

- Which logic is better and why?
- If logic 2, is it good the way i thought it up? and should i worry about the load time in the future when lot of tags will be there?

thank you

Comment: You should not worry about the load time because you will hopefully know all about database indices and how they help prevent the time escalating... :-)

Comment: It wont be a problem for example when people search for an actual tag?

Comment: You can index the tag names as well... additions are slower, searches are faster as a result.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with the second one. I wouldn't worry about load times. You can easily get the categories with joins.

However, you should add an id column on the relation table so that multiple images can share a category.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, your `relation table` should have indexes, so that when you look for all the tags based on a specific photo_id, the answer will be rapidly returned.

See also [Foreign Keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

In your `relation` table, `tag_id` is a foreign key into your tag table and `photo_id` is a foreign key into the photo table. Tags may have a relationship to more than 1 photo and a photo may have a relationship to more than one tag.

Similarly the names of your tags (and photos) should also be indexed for rapid searching.